# order of $(1,3,2,4)(4,3,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Write the $ \pi=(1,3,2,4)(4,3,5) $ as

a) product of disjoint cycles

b) product of transpositions, and is $\pi$ odd or even?

c) order of $\pi$

I think this is right $$(1,3,2,4)(4,3,5)=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 2 & 3 & 4 &5 \\ 
 3& 4 & 5 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

a) My understanding of a disjoint cycle is that each integer only appears once. so $(1,3,5)(2,4)$ are disjoint cycles?

b) $(2,4)(1,5)(1,3)$ and $\pi$ is odd

c) I have no idea on how to find the order of $\pi$ so this is where I need help or a starting off point.

Just want to know if what I did for (a) and (b) is right and how would I go about finding (c) Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers to a) and b) are correct. For c), it helps to consider the permutation in disjoint cycle form: $(1,3,5)(2,4)$. The order of any cycle is just the number of elements in that cycle. And, the order of a product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of the orders of the individual cycles. So, $|(1,3,5)(2,4)|=\operatorname{lcm}(3,2)=6$.

Comment: Note that the convention in the OPs environment is the multiplication is right to left.